# vector.push_back() improving performance

Tags: c++, performance, vector, bitmask, push-back

Is there any way to improve the performance of this function? As I have to call it ~10-100M times for 1 calculation it's slowing down my program and most time has been lost in this line:

```
myHand_param.FinalHandVector.push_back((1 << static_cast<int>(std::ceil((i - 3.0) / 4.0))));
```

I know that the vector capacity should never exceed 5 but I don't know how to skip the boundary checking, tried to work with int* instead of vector but it didn't help as well.

```
    void CalculateKickers(Hand& myHand_param, int kickersNeeded)
{
    int countKickers{ 0 };

    for(int i = bits-1; i > 0 ; i--)
    {
        if (static_cast<std::bitset<bits>>(myHand_param.handMask)[i] == 1)
        {
            if (static_cast<std::bitset<1>>((static_cast<std::bitset<bits>>(myHand_param.FinalHandUsedCardFacesMask) >> i).to_ullong())== 0)
            {
                ++countKickers;
                myHand_param.FinalHandVector.push_back((1 << static_cast<int>(std::ceil((i - 3.0) / 4.0))));

                if (countKickers == kickersNeeded)
                {
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: a) does calling `myHand_param.FinalHandVector.reserve(5);` (before the loop) help at all? b) are you compiling with optimizations enabled?

Comment: If you expect to push a bunch of values onto a vector, consider calling `reserve` up-front to avoid reallocations. Also, describe how you are benchmarking this code. Did you compile with full optimizations? Debug / unoptimized builds can run very slowly, especially with vectors. It's very unlikely that the vector size-checking alone is causing a bottleneck, just looking at how much other branching you already do. It _might_ be the reallocations, but I suspect the problem could be elsewhere.

Comment: A likely suspect is `std::ceil((i - 3.0) / 4.0)` -- a bunch of `double` arithmetic and a call to the math library. This line of code might show up as a hot path during instrumentation and lead you to believe it's the `push_back` at fault, whereas it could very well be the calculation. Consider precalculating these values in a table somewhere or at the very least use only integer arithmetic or bit manipulation to compute this.

Comment: another option, is if you can spare the extra memory, i would just store a std::array<T,5> + size, instead of a vector to avoid the dynamic allocations & extra indirections.

Comment: What bounds checking do you mean here? In optimized mode tgere should be no bounds checking in push_back...

Comment: Calls to std::ceil can be optimized as you only use positive integer arithmetic there. i / 4 is probably equivalent operation.

Comment: Those `bitset` conversions look unnecessarily complicated.